# How to write my own comparator class in java?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, treemap

I didn't find proper solution for the below scenario. I have employee names and location. In each location many employees can work.
Example: assume that employee names are unique so I consider it as a key and value as location.

```
TreeMap<String,String> t=new TreeMap<String,String>();
t.put(mike, Houston);
t.put(arian, Houston);
t.put(John, Atlanta);
```

Well my scenario is i have to write my own `comparator` where location is sorted first and when there are multiple locations of same name then they need to be sorted by `employees`. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to create a class that implements interface [`java.util.Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) <= see the API documentation. Try that first and if you have trouble, then post your code and explain what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a structure, and compareTo:

```
public class EmpLoc  implements Comparable<EmpLoc>  {
String employee;
String location;

public EmpLoc (String _employee, String _location)
    {
    employee=_employee;
    location=_location; 
    }


@Override
public int compareTo(EmpLoc other)
    {
    int last = this.location.compareTo(other.location);
    return last == 0 ? this.employee.compareTo(other.employee) : last;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your data structure. TreeMap ensure your keys are always sorted in an order, but your key doesn't have full information you need to sort. Instead what you need is probably

```
TreeSet<Employee> employees = new TreeSet<>(employeeComparator);
```

where Employee is:

```
public class Employee {
   private String name;
   private String location;
   /* getters & setters omitted */
}
```

Now you can create a comparator for Employee

Comment: Even TreeMap allows constructor with comparator
TreeMap<Employee> employees = new TreeMap<>(employeeComparator);

Comment: @DheerendraKulkarni map need two type parameters: key and value. In this scenario all the information is stored inside Employee, hence if you use a map there's no value to map the key into

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar structure:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>(<your_own_comparator_for_locations_or_default_one>);
```

This is [`Multimap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), and this is implementation by conventional means, but also there are third-party implementation, e.g. [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava). Guava has some sorted, synchronized and immutable implementations of multimaps, you can use them by default or to see how to do some things.

You can put values like below:

```
public void putEmployees(String location, String employee) {
    List<String> employees = map.get(location);
    if (employee == null) {
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    employees.add(employee);
    Collections.sort(employees, <your_own_comparator_for_employees_or_default_one>);
    map.put(location, employees);
}
```

Comment: I cannot give with third parties.